# Make text stay relative within div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble forcing the text to stay relative within its div and at the same height as the image. So when the browser is resized, it doesn't overflow. I'm doing this as I'm creating a responsive webpage. I hope I've explained this clearly. Please check out my http://jsfiddle.net/DMnhB/1/

The html is as follows:

```
<div id="postd"><img       
src="http://www.tntmagazine.com/media/content/_master/42628/images/barack-obama.jpg">

<span>
Text Here
Text Here
Text Here    
</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#postd{
width:100%;
padding-bottom: 5%;
background-color: blue;
padding-top:6%;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

#postd img{
width:40%;
}
#postd span{
float:right;margin-left:1px;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `@media` query to move the text under the image after a certain point? Also, you should have a min-width on that image. I don't really understand why you need such a narrow column of text.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DMnhB/3/?

Comment: @daniel good idea, I will use media queries. The text was not meant to be that narrow. It's just because I used <br> to many times. It was just to emphasise the fact that I wanted the height of the text to be relative to the image.

Comment: @stackErr that's nice, I shall also combine that code with media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start, try the following CSS:

```
#postd {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top:6%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
#postd img {
    width:40%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#postd span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:1px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can see how it looks at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DMnhB/2/

I used inline-blocks to fix the overflow problem and vertical-align: top to place
the top of the image inline with the top of the text block.

You need to provide some additional feedback before I make any other adjustments.

Comment: Thank you Marc. I've realised that I'll only be able to achieve full relativeness by using media queries, combined with the code that you just provided, which fixed the overflow problem.